# When are ㅅ and ㅆ pronounced as stops?

Tags: pronunciation, hangul

I thought that ㅅ is pronounced /t̚/ at the end of a syllable block, but it seems to be an /s/ in 것은, even though [것](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EA%B2%83) on its own is /kʌ̹t̚/.

Does it depend on word boundaries, or is it just irregular?

Comment: ...I need to go learn IPA notation...

Comment: @RCIX /k/, more rounded UH, and /t/ with no audible release. That’s it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ㅆ (/s͈/) and ㅅ (/s<sup>h</sup>/) are pronounced as /t̚/ whenever the following conditions are all met:

1. ㅅ/ㅆ is on the 받침 (the final consonant of a block).
2. ㅅ/ㅆ is not immediately followed by ㅇ in the initial position of the next block.
3. ㅅ/ㅆ is not immediately followed by one of the other nasal consonants (ㄴ and ㅁ) in the initial position of the next block.

This means that:

- 있어 is pronounced the same as 이써 /is͈ʌ/ (Condition #2 is *not* met).
- 있는 is pronounced the same as 인는 /innɯn/ (Condition #3 is *not* met).
- 있다 is pronounced the same as 읻따 /it̚t͈a/ (All the conditions are met).

Comment: If ㅅ is immediately followed by ㄹ in the initial position of the next block, the ㅅㄹ is pronounced as ㄴㄴ (/nn/). You will find this when some Koreans read loanwords such as 핫라인 ("hotline"), 풋라이트 ("footlight"), and 마켓 리더 ("market leader"); they pronounce 핫라인 as 한나인, 풋라이트 as 푼나이트, and 마켓 리더 as 마켄니더. However, please note that there are no official rules regarding how to pronounce loanwords.

Comment: @Klmo I would pronounce those as 할라인, 풀라이트, 마켈리더. I think this is a free variation, and a native speaker will equally recognize either direction of assimilation. The "official" rule explicitly refuses assimilation in such situation, however. (See 표준발음법 21항.)

Comment: @Taegyung Although [the National Institute of Korean Language allows both 온나인 and 올라인 for 온라인](https://www.korean.go.kr/front/onlineQna/onlineQnaView.do?mn_id=216&qna_seq=136545), pronouncing 핫라인 as 한나인 is more reasonable because of [표준 발음법 제19항](http://kornorms.korean.go.kr/regltn/regltnView.do?regltn_code=0002#a412). "제19항에 대한 다른 의견" mentions why ㄷ was excluded, which implies that ㄷㄹ could be taken as ㄴㄴ. I deem that 제20항 cannot be applied to 핫라인 because 핫라인 is *not* 한라인; 핫라인 should first be taken as 핟 + 라인. In addition, pronouncing 핫라 as 할라 may confuse listeners and they think of 한라.

Comment: The correct pronunciation of 곶리도, which is not a loanword, is 곤니도; you can notice "ㅈ → [ㄷ]" and "ㄷㄹ → [ㄴㄴ]." The same rule would be applied to 핫라인 if it were not a loanword.

Comment: @Taegyung I have found that a grammar book, "한국어의 발음" by 배주채, mentions that 핫라인 is pronounced as 한나인 [(link here)](https://www.korean.go.kr/front/onlineQna/onlineQnaView.do?mn_id=216&qna_seq=112274). Now, it is certain that we should pronounce ㄷㄹ (and also ㅅㄹ, ㅈㄹ, ...) as ㄴㄴ.

Answer (score 2):

Refer back to your pronunciation rules for this one. You're correct that ㅅ and ㅆ exhibit closure as 받침. But in this case, you have a ㅅ and an ㅇ next to each other in the order that they will be read. For that reason, re-syllabification occurs.

So, instead of 것은 -> 거-뜬 or 거-튼, it's 것은 -> 거슨.

Hope this helps!